# any Java IDE's Web Application Authentication template equivalent to Visual Studio's built-in

Tags: java, visual-studio-2012, netbeans

Does JDeveloper, Netbeans or any other Java IDE have template for authentication similar to  Visual Studio's built-in template for Authentication in starting a Web Application Project. So it does not require any coding to implement sign in/registration/password recovery...etc and it's easy to modify database connection setting through config file. 
Is there an equivalent authentication method template in a Java IDE?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have probably been using VS , I would say go with eclipse because it has various plug-in's especially for VS. Look if they have plug-in's for that so you can avoid that hassle. If you have your data  stored in a file you can go to googletakeout.com and it will unzip your file and move it to new file where you can then port that to eclipse. that's all I got, correct me if I am wrong though.